# Under construction web security

Tags: security

I have some ideas for some web projects that have the potential to go big.  However, they involve server-side scripting and would take a few weeks to make, so they would have weeks of exposure to the public before the beta is even out.  How do I keep a site secure enough that only people working on the site can see the material being made?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a local development server (configured as closely as possible to the production/live server), rather than a public-facing web-accessible server. If the people working on the development are based in other offices/places/work-from-home, then you could maybe look at setting up a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN) to allow them to access the development server from their place of work.

In addition to this use some form of access control (username/password), possibly including IP address restriction (though this could be tricky if your devs don't have fixed IP addresses).

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable anonymous browsing
2. Add a password to your site
3. Filter who can see the site by IP